# .NET - Use method as a parameter of another method

Tags: c#, .net, exception, methods, delegates

I want to use any method as a parameter of a method that cares about exception handling, something like this:

```
public void Run(){
    string result1 = (string)HandlingMethod(GiveMeString, "Hello");
    int result2 = (int)HandlingMethod(CountSomething, 1, 2);
}

public object HandlingMethod(something method, manyDifferentTypesOfParameters...){
    try{
        return method(manyDifferentTypesOfParameters)
    }catch(Exception ex){
        ....
    }
}

public string GiveMeString(string text){
    return text + "World";
}

public int CountSomething(int n1, int n2){
    return n1 + n2;
}
```

Is it possible to do it in C# .Net?

**EDIT:**

I found this solution, but I'm not sure how safe and ok it is. What do you think?

```
public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string result1 = (string)Test(new Func<string,string>(TestPrint), "hello");
            int result2 = (int)Test(new Func<int, int, int>(TestPrint2), 4, 5);
            Console.WriteLine(result1);
            Console.WriteLine(result2);
        }

        public static object Test(Delegate method, params object[] args){
            Console.WriteLine("test test");
            return method.DynamicInvoke(args);
        }

        public static string TestPrint(string text){
           return text;
        }

        public static int TestPrint2(int n1, int n2){
            return n1 + n2 +1;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't think you can do such generic things.

Comment: _"I'm not sure how safe and ok it is"_ -- the example you found is the most efficient, as it creates a delegate that will call your method directly, with the arguments you provide. But, it is not as convenient as requiring the caller to wrap their call in an anonymous method (typically represented as a lambda expression). The latter avoids the need to explicitly create a delegate (e.g. by casting or using `new`), which makes the code a bit more readable/concise.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass delegates in C#.

There are two types:

- Action: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.action-1?view=netframework-4.8
- Function: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.func-2?view=netframework-4.8

Action don't have any return Value, Function do have return Value. 
The only Problem I see here, is that you need so specify the parameters of the delegate, when you write the Method. Of course you could pass object[] as Parameter, but I don't think it's a good idea

Comment: why dont you recommend me to use the  object[]?

Comment: I edited the question with one solution, what do you think about it?

Comment: @BananaCake if you use an object[] as param, you loose basically all benefits of a statically typed language. You have to check, if you received enough arguments, if the arguments are not null, if the arguments are the correct type and you have to cast them to the according type. If you pass the wrong kind of type, you could receive random exceptions

Answer (score -2):

You can create generic handling methods for every number of parameters:

```
    public RetType HandlingMethod<P1Type,RetType>(Func<P1Type, RetType> method, P1Type p)
    {
        return method(p);
    }

    public RetType HandlingMethod<P1Type, P2Type, RetType>(Func<P1Type, P2Type, RetType> method, P1Type p1, P2Type p2)
    {
        return method(p1, p2);
    }
```

Comment: This will just double my methods. I want to create one method for everything.

Comment: I edited the question with one solution, what do you think about it?

Comment: A1. OK, doubled handlers, but they can be used for every other target methods with one or two params 
A2. with object type you loose type safety (as Thomas said)